# Korn/Bash Shell: How to do I convert the contents to the below format?

Tags: linux, text-processing

```
 pid        name          tid        mod         state   data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
39523      srv0051_0001_0  39642      20-10:59:28 Working 820000:500196:500077 
43137      srv0051_0005_0  43156      20-10:59:28 Working 820000:4250501:840057
43895      srv0051_0006_0  43903      20-10:59:28 Working 820000:4250501:840057
47523      srv0051_0009_0  47547      20-10:59:28 Working 600005:4250501:4250846
48841      srv0051_0010_0  48851      20-10:59:28 Working 600005:4290000:4290000
58182      srv0051_0020_0  58188      20-10:59:28 Working 820000:4250501:840057
8297       srv0079_0008_0  8316       20-10:59:27 Working 600005:3070001:3050012



pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username
39523,srv0051_0001_0,39642,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,500196,500077
43137,srv0051_0005_0,43156,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
43895,srv0051_0006_0,43903,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
47523,srv0051_0009_0,47547,20-10:59:28,Working,600005,4250501,4250846
48841,srv0051_0010_0,48851,20-10:59:28,Working,600005,4290000,4290000
58182,srv0051_0020_0,58188,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
8297,srv0079_0008_0,8316,20-10:59:27,Working,600005,3070001,3050012
```

Comment: pray tell, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @steve I'm very new to scripting so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Your header has more fields than the data. Is this on purpose?

Comment: OK, which of the two is original and which is the desired result ?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes. The second is the desired state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed '
    # delete the 2nd line
    2d

    # remove any leading whitespace
    s/^[[:blank:]]\+//

    # on line 1, replace "data" with other words
    1s/data/appnbr request tasknbr appctx username/

    # replace any sequences of whitespace with comma
    s/[[:blank:]]\+/,/g

    # replace the 3rd and subsequent colons
    s/:/,/3g
' file
```

Required GNU sed for the `s///3g` action

Comment: GNU sed also needed for `\+`.  Standard equivalent is `\{1,\}`

Comment: @glennjackman I'm confuse. How would the entire command look like?

Comment: Your confusion confuses me: that's the whole thing right there. Copy and paste it into your terminal.

Comment: Is it because it's a multiline script with comments? Newlines are valid within quotes

Comment: @glennjackman How would command look like without the comments?

Comment: You could just remove those lines. Or, you could use semicolons instead of newlines: `sed '2d; s/^[[:blank:]]\+//; 1s/data/appnbr request tasknbr appctx username/; s/[[:blank:]]\+/,/g; s/:/,/3g' file` if you enjoy hard-to-maintain code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
grep -v "^-" test.txt | tr -s " " ',' |  sed -e s/:/,/3g -e '0,/data/ s/data/appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username/'
```

Comment: A tweak needed to cover the conversion of `:` to `,` in the final column ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -f script.awk file.txt
pid,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username
39523,srv0051_0001_0,39642,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,500196,500077
43137,srv0051_0005_0,43156,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
43895,srv0051_0006_0,43903,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
47523,srv0051_0009_0,47547,20-10:59:28,Working,600005,4250501,4250846
48841,srv0051_0010_0,48851,20-10:59:28,Working,600005,4290000,4290000
58182,srv0051_0020_0,58188,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
8297,srv0079_0008_0,8316,20-10:59:27,Working,600005,3070001,3050012
```

Where `script.awk` is

```
BEGIN   { OFS = "," } # set output delimiter

NR == 1 {
    # modify some fields of the header
    $6 = "appnbr"
    $7 = "request"
    $8 = "tasknbr"
    $9 = "appctx"
    $10 = "username"
}

NR == 2 { next } # skip line 2

NR > 2 {
    # split the sixth field on ":" and extend the record with the bits
    split($6, a, ":")
    $6 = a[1]
    $7 = a[2]
    $8 = a[3]
}

1 # print
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my `awk` stab at it.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "id,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username"}NR>2{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","gensub(/:/,",","g",$6)}' file.txt
```

- NR>2 so that record number 1 and 2 (headers) are skipped
- print fields $1 thru $5 with commas
- instead of printing field $6, print it with `:` replaced with ","

Comment: How would I do the new headers aspect?

Comment: now added the headers part.

Comment: The previous second line (-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ) reappear. I also would like to append those columns name to the same line pid,name,tid,mod.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane 'print join ",", @F[0..$#F-1], $. == 1 ? qw/appnbr request tasknbr appctx username/ : split /:/, $F[-1] unless $. == 2' input-file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
id,name,tid,mod,state,appnbr,request,tasknbr,appctx,username
39523,srv0051_0001_0,39642,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,500196,500077
43137,srv0051_0005_0,43156,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
43895,srv0051_0006_0,43903,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
47523,srv0051_0009_0,47547,20-10:59:28,Working,600005,4250501,4250846
48841,srv0051_0010_0,48851,20-10:59:28,Working,600005,4290000,4290000
58182,srv0051_0020_0,58188,20-10:59:28,Working,820000,4250501,840057
8297,srv0079_0008_0,8316,20-10:59:27,Working,600005,3070001,3050012
```

**Explanation:**

1. Split each line, a.k.a., record, on whitespace(s) and store the reultant fields in the array `@F`. Array is indexed from `0` and goes all the way to `$#F`. So `$#F-1` is the second last element.
2. All lines except the 2nd are to be processed, in that the last element is the deciding factor.
3. For the first line, the last element is replaced by multiple field names.
4. For the remaining, (remember 2nd is already discarded) are split up on `:` and these split up fields come in place of  the last element.
5. The joining of all the elements is done by the `,` and then printed to `stdout`.

With `POSIX sed`, we can do the following:

```
sed -e '
   2d
   s/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//;s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ /g ;# trim n squeeze blanks
   1s/data$/appnbr request tasknbr appctx username/            ;# line 1 spl processing
   y/:/\n/         ;# change all colons to newlines
   s/\n/:/;s//:/   ;# undo the transformation for the first 2
   y/\n/ /         ;# change the rest to blanks
   y/ /,/          ;# now change these and the already existing blanks to commas
' input-file.txt
```